# Kendo-Grid sorting on kendoGridHeaderTemplate

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

It appears that when progress updated kendo-grid to 3.6.1 the [changelog](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/changelog/) says "sortChange is not emitted on click of a non focusable element in the header tem".

Previously, in 3.6.0 and below, we had implimented some custom filtering and displaying using the kendoGridHeaderTemplate like so:

```
                    <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-dataItem let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
                    <span id="{{col.DisplayName}}-header"></span>
                    {{col.DisplayName}}
                    <span id="filter-popover-button-{{col.DisplayName}}" #filterPopoverButton (click)="col['showColumnFilter']= !col['showColumnFilter']">
                        <i [class]="col['hasFilter']? 'ld-icon filter-blue-active':'ld-icon filter-green'"
                            aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align:text-bottom;"></i>
                    </span>
                    <kendo-popup *ngIf="col['showColumnFilter']" [anchor]="filterPopoverButton">
                        <span class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" style="padding: 0px;margin-right: 25px;margin-top: 5px;"
                                (click)="col['showColumnFilter'] = false">
                                <span aria-hidden="true" style="text-shadow: none;">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        <columnFilter-component [column]="col"></columnFilter-component>
                    </kendo-popup>
                </ng-template>
```

In this code there is a filter icon that opens a kendo-popover with a custom filter/display.  Now when we upgraded to 3.7.1, clicking on this icon causes the grid to sort/refresh.
I believe that this is to the update in 3.6.1 mentioned above.

#### Is it possible to have a item in kendoGridHeaderTemplate that does not trigger a sort event?

We do want the grid sortable, but not when they click to open the filter popup.